# Visual Studio 2017 Live Testing exclusions

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm looking at Live Testing feature in the new Visual Studio (I'm using NUnit).

There is an "exclude" option for unit tests, to indicate that specific tests should not be run (maybe they are integration tests, or slow tests, or whatever).

[image]

Where does this information get stored? I don't see any indication in the csproj or anywhere else that a test should not be included in Live Testing. Shouldn't there be some information file somewhere that I can check into source control so the rest of my team doesn't have to manually specify which tests should not be run by live testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include/exclude is a user level feature. This is extremely useful when you want to run a specific set of tests for a particular edit session or to persist your own personal preferences.  To prevent tests from running and to persist that information, you could do something like the following:

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class SkipLiveFactAttribute : FactAttribute
{
    private static bool s_lutRuntimeLoaded = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.GetName().Name == "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.Runtime");

    public override string Skip => s_lutRuntimeLoaded ? "Test excluded from Live Unit Testing" : "";
}

public class Class1
{
    [SkipLiveFact]
    public void F()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. I tried [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] on both the test method and the test fixture. The test still runs.

Comment: Yes this only prevents visualization, test still get run. This may help:
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class SkipLiveFactAttribute : FactAttribute
{
private static bool s_lutRuntimeLoaded = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(a => a.GetName().Name == "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LiveUnitTesting.Runtime");
public override string Skip => s_lutRuntimeLoaded ? "Test excluded from Live Unit Testing" : "";
}

public class Class1
{
[SkipLiveFact]
public void F()
{
Assert.True(true);
}
}

Comment: I have updated the answer above and also removed text about ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute which was incorrect.

Comment: So, that solution works for xUnit (I think). I'm using NUnit, but I imagine there's something similar I could write. What I was hoping for was some sort of generic way to do this that wasn't specific to a testing framework.

Comment: thanks was looking for the ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute!!

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the following attributes to specify in source code that you want to exclude targeted test methods from Live Unit Testing:

```
For xUnit: [Trait("Category", "SkipWhenLiveUnitTesting")]
For NUnit: [Category("SkipWhenLiveUnitTesting")]
For MSTest: [TestCategory("SkipWhenLiveUnitTesting")]
```

Offical Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing-whats-new?view=vs-2017)